# CodeIgniter pagination. Unsure how to implement

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am having trouble implementing the CodeIgniter pagination class that comes with the CI base install.

I have a page which shows news articles and shows them on a page. I want to show a maximum of 5 articles per page and have the pagination to browse through these pages.

I have read the CI documentation but I am unsure as to what I am supposed to be pointing the config['base_url'] variable to. Here is my code (please bear in mind I have removed code from the examples which is not relevant with this issue):

Controller:

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
//Get News Articles
        $options = array(
            'orderBy' => 'DESC'
        );
        $newsArticles = $this->admin_model->getNewsArticles($options);
        $data['newsArticles'] = array();
        foreach($newsArticles as $newsArticle) { 
            $date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($newsArticle['date_created']));
            $active = ($newsArticle['active'] == 1 ? 'tick.png' : 'cross.png');
            $data['newsArticles'][] = array(
                'articleId'  =>  $newsArticle['news_id'],
                'title'      =>  $newsArticle['title'],
                'content'    =>  htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($newsArticle['content'])),
                'date'       =>  $date,
                'author'     =>  $newsArticle['author'],
                'active'     =>  $this->config->base_url() . "/images/" . $active,
                'link'       =>  $this->config->base_url() . "/index.php/admin/newsPage?articleId=" . $newsArticle['news_id']
            );
        }

        //Pagination

        $config['base_url'] = $this->config->base_url() . "index.php/news/getNewsArticles";
        $config['total_rows'] = 200;
        $config['per_page'] = 20; 

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

The model function is simply a function which returns the news articles and is working in fine here.

Do I need to point the base_url variable to a function that returns the database results straight to the pagination class? I am unsure as tho how it is implemented.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or advise as to where I am going wrong that would be great.

Comment: hello, CIs pagination is awesome and easy to use, please go watch some tutorials first (not all of them only those that interest you) its well explained. Here is the source http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/ .

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I managed to get it working by following this tutorial.

Comment: also note that `$offset` can be a last parameter of your controllers method ;) like this `public function method($arg1 = '', $arg2 = '', $offset = 0) { }`, also note that it wont work on `index()` method you will have to `_remap()`. Have a good day.

Comment: You should be loading the url_helper instead of going around writing $this->config->base_url, you can use base_url() instead. And Please do not use base_url for pagination use site_url function instead e.g: site_url("news/index")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to get it working after checking the Ellislab tutorials. Here is the revised controller. Please note that in my model function I also added a clause to catch the offset.

```
//Pagination
        $config['base_url']   = $this->config->base_url() . "index.php/news/news/index";
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->admin_model->getMaxNewsRows();
        $config['per_page']   = 5;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['num_links']  = 5; 
        $config['next_link']        = 'Next';
        $config['next_tag_open']    = '<span class="nextPage">';
        $config['next_tag_close']   = '</span>';
        $config['prev_link']        = 'Prev';
        $config['prev_tag_open']    = '<span class="prevPage">';
        $config['prev_tag_close']   = '</span>';
        $config['cur_tag_open']     = '<span class="active_page">';
        $config['cur_tag_close']    = '</span>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);     

        //Get News Articles
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(4);

        $options = array(
            'orderBy' => 'DESC',
            'limit' => $config['per_page']
        );
        if($offset != 0) {
            $options['offset'] = $offset;
        }
        $newsArticles = $this->admin_model->getNewsArticles($options);
        //$newsArticles = $this->db->get('news', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));

        $data['newsArticles'] = array();
        foreach($newsArticles as $newsArticle) { 
            $date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($newsArticle['date_created']));
            $active = ($newsArticle['active'] == 1 ? 'tick.png' : 'cross.png');
            $data['newsArticles'][] = array(
                'articleId'  =>  $newsArticle['news_id'],
                'title'      =>  $newsArticle['title'],
                'content'    =>  htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($newsArticle['content'])),
                'date'       =>  $date,
                'author'     =>  $newsArticle['author'],
                'active'     =>  $this->config->base_url() . "/images/" . $active,
                'link'       =>  $this->config->base_url() . "/index.php/admin/newsPage?articleId=" . $newsArticle['news_id']
            );
        }       
        $data['pagLinks'] =  $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public function index() {
//Get News Articles
$options = array(
    'orderBy' => 'DESC'
);

#pagination start
$perPage                    = 20;   #rows per page 
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url']         = base_url().'index.php/news/getNewsArticles/';
$config['total_rows']       = $this->admin_model->count_getNewsArticles( $options ); #should return the total rows in integer
$config['per_page']         = $perPage;
$config["uri_segment"]      = 3;
$config['next_link']        = 'Next';
$config['next_tag_open']    = '<span class="nextPage">';
$config['next_tag_close']   = '</span>';
$config['prev_link']        = 'Prev';
$config['prev_tag_open']    = '<span class="prevPage">';
$config['prev_tag_close']   = '</span>';
$config['cur_tag_open']     = '<span class="active_page">';
$config['cur_tag_close']    = '</span>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
#pagination end
$data['links']              = $this->pagination->create_links();

$newsArticles = $this->admin_model->getNewsArticles($options, $perPage, $this->uri->segment(3));
$data['newsArticles'] = array();
foreach($newsArticles as $newsArticle) { 
    $date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($newsArticle['date_created']));
    $active = ($newsArticle['active'] == 1 ? 'tick.png' : 'cross.png');
    $data['newsArticles'][] = array(
        'articleId'  =>  $newsArticle['news_id'],
        'title'      =>  $newsArticle['title'],
        'content'    =>  htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($newsArticle['content'])),
        'date'       =>  $date,
        'author'     =>  $newsArticle['author'],
        'active'     =>  $this->config->base_url() . "/images/" . $active,
        'link'       =>  $this->config->base_url() . "/index.php/admin/newsPage?articleId=" . $newsArticle['news_id']
    );
}


###changes in the model function

function getNewsArticles($options, $perPage, $offset = 0){
    $this->db->get('table_name', $limit, $offset); #in query
}
```